# Assigning new Array to NodeList.prototype

Tags: javascript, dom

Why is not possible to inherit array props and methods when I set `NodeList.prototype` to `Array object` like this -
`NodeList.prototype = new Array;` and I can do that with my custom constructor prototype ? Why first `a` object does not inherit array methods and `aa` does ? 
Any explanation or blog post link about this is welcome.

```
function A(a) {
 this.a = a;
}

A.prototype.b = 'b';

var a = new A('a');

A.prototype = new Array; // aa instance will now have map, filter, some ...

var aa = new A('aa');
```

Comment: Rather than screwing around with prototypes, do it properly. `[].map.call(list,function(...) {...});` and such.

Comment: I know but I need to understand what is going on, how this works.

Comment: You're trying to do something you shouldn't, and the browser is saying "no".

Comment: You may just want [NodeList.js](https://github.com/eorroe/NodeList.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the prototype of native objects (e.g. NodeList) is always risky. It might or might not work. It's much better to extend the prototype or extend the actual object.

```
NodeList.prototype.map = Array.prototype.map;
// or:
someNodeList.map = Array.prototype.map;
```

And to exaplain you example: When you create a new object, it takes the prototype of the constructor and stores its reference to its `__proto__` property. So if you completely replace the prototype of some constructor, it will affect only newly created objects, because they will have a reference to the new prototype.

Comment: He is. I think you missed the `NodeList.prototype = new Array;` part.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the prototype chain is set at construction time. Calling `A.prototype = new Array;` will only affect instances created after that.

To change the prototype of an object after it has been instantiated, you could use  [`Object.setPrototypeOf(a)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)

Lastly, note that in your example, you are obliterating the existing prototype so all new instances of `A` will not have the original `b: "b"` property.